# openCV Js add and subtract giving unexpected results

Tags: javascript, opencv

I am using gaussianBlur to get the high pass of the image but it seems like cv.subtract() function does not subtract two images pixel by pixel. I confirmed this by first subtracting the blurred image from input image and then adding the blurred image again to the result. On doing so, the output should be the same as the input image but it is different.

```
    img=src
    cv.GaussianBlur(img, blur, new cv.Size(21, 21), 0,0,cv.BORDER_DEFAULT)
    let x = new cv.Mat()
    let y = new cv.Mat()
    cv.subtract(img,blur,x)
    cv.add(x,blur,y)
```

Here are the images for reference [input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opW4M.png), [blurred image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDpKt.png), [output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KAMb.png)

Comment: Look carefully at the size of both the original image and the blurred image. Both images should be of the same size but they aren't. Now, the convolution during the blurring operation causes the reduction of n rows and m columns (the border) of the original image, however, OpenCV handles this problem via the border mode, which is the last parameter of the function to preserve the original size. Why is this apparently failing here? I don't know, the function call seems ok, but I'm not familiar with the JS implementation of OpenCV. However, it appears that your images are not completely aligned.

Comment: opencv **clamps** ops like subtract & add to e.g. [0..255]. so `3 - 7 = 0`. (not `-4` , unsigned char !) you loose information this way, that you cannot recover.

Comment: again, to avoid the loss, convert images from CV_8U to something like CV_16S before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, `cv.add` and `cv.subtract` functions clip the `uint8` summed/subtracted elements to range [0, 255].
The solution is converting the `mat` data type from `uint8` to larger data type as `int16`.

---

Example for clipping (pseudocode):
`cv.add(uint8(200), uint8(100))` equals `uint8(255)` (instead of 300).
`cv.subtract(uint8(10), uint8(20))` equals `uint8(0)` (instead of -10).

That means that computing: `uint8(200)` + `uint8(100)` - `uint8(100)`, results `155` (instead of getting back to the original value 200).

The solution is converting `mat` data type from `uint8` to larger data type as `int16`.
`int16` elements are clipped to range [-32768, 32767], and we are not getting close to these range limits.

Computing: `int16(200)` + `int16(100)` - `int16(100)`, results `200` (because int16(200) + int16(100) = int16(300). No clipping occurs...

---

Converting from `uint8` to `int16` is performed using [convertTo](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#adf88c60c5b4980e05bb556080916978b) member function:

```
img.convertTo(img2, cv.CV_16S);
blur.convertTo(blur2, cv.CV_16S);
```

Then apply `cv.subtract` and `cv.add` to the `int16` elements:

```
cv.subtract(img2, blur2, x)
cv.add(x, blur2, y)
```

At the end, we may convert the result back to `uint8` type:

```
y.convertTo(out, cv.CV_8U);
```

---

Here is a sample that applies the above procedure, and verifies that `out` = `img`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Hello OpenCV.js</title>
</head>

<body>
<p id="status">OpenCV.js is loading...</p>
<div>
  <div class="inputoutput">
    <img id="imageSrc" alt="No Image" />
    <div class="caption">imageSrc <input type="file" id="fileInput" name="file" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="inputoutput">
    <canvas id="canvasOutput" ></canvas>
    <div class="caption">canvasOutput</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script async src="opencv.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
let imgElement = document.getElementById('imageSrc');
let inputElement = document.getElementById('fileInput');
inputElement.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  imgElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
}, false);

//read image
imgElement.onload = function () {
  let img = cv.imread(imgElement);
  let blur = new cv.Mat();
  let x = new cv.Mat();
  let y = new cv.Mat();  
  let img2 = new cv.Mat();
  let blur2 = new cv.Mat();
  let out = new cv.Mat();
  
  cv.GaussianBlur(img, blur, new cv.Size(21, 21), 0, 0, cv.BORDER_DEFAULT);
  
  img.convertTo(img2, cv.CV_16S); //Convert img from type Uint8Array to type Int16Array
  blur.convertTo(blur2, cv.CV_16S); //Convert blur from type Uint8Array to type Int16Array
  
  cv.subtract(img2, blur2, x) //Subtract applies Int16 elements (instead of Uint8 elements).
  cv.add(x, blur2, y) //Add applies Int16 elements (instead of Uint8 elements).
  
  y.convertTo(out, cv.CV_8U); //Convert y from type Int16Array to type Uint8Array (out is used as input for imshow).
  cv.imshow('canvasOutput', out);
  
  
  let d = new cv.Mat();
  cv.absdiff(out, img, d);
   
  //Compute the sum of absolute difference (for testing)
  let sum_abs_dif = 0
  for (row = 0; row < d.rows; row++) {
    for (col = 0; col < d.cols; col++) {
      sum_abs_dif += d.ucharPtr(row, col)[0] + d.ucharPtr(row, col)[1] + d.ucharPtr(row, col)[2];
      //d.ucharPtr(row, col)[3] = 255; //Set the alpha (transparency) channel to 255 for testing.
    }
  } 
 
  console.log(sum_abs_dif)  //Prints 0
  
  img.delete();
  blur.delete();
  x.delete();
  y.delete();
  img2.delete();
  blur2.delete();
  out.delete();
  d.delete();
};


//check openCV
var Module = {
  // https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/module.html#Module.onRuntimeInitialized
  onRuntimeInitialized() {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'OpenCV.js is ready.';
  }
};
</script>


</body>
</html>
```